# iOS 7 Sprite Kit speed change for animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have a `runAction` which is animating a `SKSpriteNode`. I have the node moving up and down in a `repeatActionForever`. I would like the node to slow down as the node is moving up and speed up as the node is moving down.

```
[node runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
                       [SKAction sequence:@
                        [[SKAction speedTo:0.1 duration:0.5],
                         [SKAction moveToY:2 * node.size.height / 3 duration:0.5],
                         [SKAction speedTo:1 duration:0.5],
                         [SKAction moveToY:node.size.height / 2 duration:0.5],
                         [SKAction moveToY:node.size.height duration:1],
                         [SKAction moveToY:node.size.height / 2 duration:1]]]]];
```

When I add the line `[SKAction speedTo:0 duration:0.5]`, the rest of the code is run at speed of 0 after the 0.5 seconds even though I added a second speedTo action which would increase the speed to 1.

**The problem**: How do I change the speed of a node as the node is moving rather than having a stagnant speed for each direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think once speed equals 0 the actions stop running, the node is effectively paused.

Comment: How would I go about changing the speed of the first action when it is moving up to slow down and the second action when the node is moving down to speed up?

Comment: You might be able to use SKAction timingMode, this allows various modes including ... ease-in (i.e. Ease-in pacing causes the animation to begin slowly, and then speed up as it progresses) or ease-out (Ease-out pacing causes the animation to begin quickly, and then slow as it completes). >>> Lookup timingMode in the Apple SKAction Class Reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up the various types of `SKActionTimingMode` and apply the ones as needed to your situation. This will remove the need for anything like `[SKAction speedTo:0.1 duration:0.5]`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SKActionTimingMode

You can use the `SKActionTimingEaseOut` for the action that makes the node move up and `SKActionTimingEaseIn` for the action that makes the node move down.

```
SKAction *actionMoveUp = [SKAction moveToY:2 * node.size.height / 3 duration:0.5];
actionMoveUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;

SKAction *actionMoveDown = [SKAction moveToY:node.size.height / 2 duration:0.5];
actionMoveDown.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseIn;

SKAction *actionMoveUpHalf = [SKAction moveToY:node.size.height duration:1];
actionMoveUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;

[node runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
                       [SKAction sequence:@
                        [actionMoveUp,
                         actionMoveDown,
                         actionMoveUpHalf,
                         actionMoveDown]]]];
```